# Refer a string as a field API name

Tags: apex, trigger, string

Is it possible to refer a string as a field API name?

I'm trying to achieve something like below:

```
Method(string fieldAPI){
   Contact con = new Contact();
   con.fieldAPI = 'Abc';
   update con;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"refer a string"*? Do you mean *"reference a string"*?

Comment: I mean instead of Field API name, I would like to use string variable, which will contain my API name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have will still work because you are referring the field name here.

```
con.fieldName__c = 'Abc';
```

You can additionally use [`Sobject.put(fieldName, value)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject) here if you want to refer the API name as string value, as:

```
con.put('fieldName__c', 'Abc');
```

Comment: Doesn't "refer" / "referring" go hand in hand with "to"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen English was never my first language :), if you feel it can be corrected/improved, please feel free to edit it.